# Nest Js - In multer interceptor how to set max file upload size and make optional file upload

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, multer

I want to set the maximum file upload size of a file and make it optional to upload file. If there is file upload then its maximum size must not exceed and if there is no file upload then it must not ask for file on server and must not throw any error.

```
@Post("fileUpload")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  private async fileUpload(
    @UploadedFile()
    file,
    @Body() body
  ) {
       console.log(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ParseFilePipeBuiler** can be used to handle:

`import { ParseFilePipeBuilder, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';`

```js
@Post("fileUpload")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  private async fileUpload(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
      .addMaxSizeValidator({
        maxSize: "MAX_FILE_SIZE"
      })
      .build({
        fileIsRequired: false
      })
    )
    file,
    @Body() body
  ) {
    console.log(file);
  }
}
```